# error using regex - expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, discord.py

Posted previously but I made some edits (which are most likely wrong)
My script watches for any posts that contain a want to sell ad, some people post their price in the form of "2.1k" (or similar, 1k, 3.5k etc)

My script reads the message and separates the price and stores it as "price" and sends that on a discord embed. The issue I was having was that it would see some messages and use words with the letter "K" as the price. One example a post said

```
"Buy from Truster seller (60+ Refs)
Lifetime - £4100 // $5300 Obo
Renewal -£3500 // $4500 Obo
US Wire/UK Bank Transfer, Transferwise, PayPal, BTC, Stripe, Rev
Discount for cash in UK
```

And the price sent was the word "Bank"

I have never used regex before, please let me know if I have even done it correctly and what I could do to change it.

```
        check1 = False
        check2 = True
        for x in message.content.lower():
            print(x)
            if x == "k":
                check1 = True
            elif x == "$":
                check1 = True
            elif x == "£":
                check1 = True
        if check1 and check2: #both success so must be correct
            print("Is not a dm and includes a price")
            split_message = message.content.split(" ")
            messageNoBold = message.content.replace('**','')
            price = None
            thePrice = re.findall("\d+(\.\d+)?[kK]", split_message)
            for x in thePrice:
                
                if "$" in x:
   
                        price = x
                        
                elif "£" in x:
                    
                        price = x
                        
                elif "k" in x:
                    
                        price = x
                        
            print(price)
```

returns -

```
return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `split_message` variable is a list and not a string. You would need to apply the regex to each string in the list, like this:

```
for item in split_message:
    thePrice = re.findall("\d+(\.\d+)?[kK]", split_message)
         for x in thePrice:
                
                if "$" in x:
   
                        price = x
                        
                elif "£" in x:
                    
                        price = x
                        
                elif "k" in x:
                    
                        price = x
```

That handles the error you are seeing and should mitigate it successfully. The tabs /spaces are screwed up in this example, so don't just copy and paste.